# How to bind HtmlString?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

Text that I must have displayed is displayed fine in my textbox and showcased as I would want it. But the problem is when I need to update the text so it tells me that there is nothing so it tells me it has a null value.

It exists in the database with text.

**index.cshtml**

```
@model MVCOrdklar2015.Models.Admin.IndholdViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "AdminIndhold", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(i => i.IndholdText, new
                   {
                       @class = "ckeditor"
                   })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group form-actions">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary">Opdater</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

Model:

```
namespace MVCOrdklar2015.Models.Admin
{
    public class IndholdViewModel
    {
        public HtmlString IndholdText
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Index(IndholdViewModel ModelInput)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DataLinqDB db = new DataLinqDB();
            var forsideindhold = db.forsides.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1);
            if (forsideindhold != null)
            {
                //error here
                forsideindhold.tekst = new HtmlString(ModelInput.IndholdText.ToString()).ToString();

                db.SubmitChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("index/Opdater");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

You can see the picture here, see what it tells me the error.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default model-binder would not bind a `HtmlString` property without registering a custom model-binder for it.

Try to use `string` combined with `[AllowHtml]` attribute instead:

```
[AllowHtml]
public string IndholdText
{
    get; set;
}
```

And in your controller:

```
forsideindhold.tekst = ModelInput.IndholdText;
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the fast HELP! :) hope you have a Merry Christmas and Happy New Year. Hope you will give me +1 for my question.